# Showing the values of JQuery Autocomplete after satisfying if condition

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery Autocomplete to return X1 values after the user typed a text that is equal to the array below:

```
var stt_start = [
   "I am interested",
   "it is",    
]
```

I added the below code to check while the user is typing if the text is equal to the array **stt_start** and if so to show the values of X1.

```
$("#autocomplete").keyup(function(event) {
   var stt=$(this).val();
       $("h3").text(stt);

   if($.inArray(stt, stt_start) > -1){
       function split( val ) {
           return val.split( / \s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }

       $( "#autocomplete" )
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                    response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        X1, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                },
                focus: function() {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    var terms = split( this.value );
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push( ui.item.value );
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push( "" );
                    this.value = terms.join( " " );
                    return false;
                }

            });

    }
});
```

You can find the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cuoa3Lfe/36/

The code is working if you try it the first time, but if the user deleted what he was typing and start from the beginning the values of X1 will be shown directly without checking if the user typed a text equal to **stt_start**.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: @Learning in the link you can see that X1 values are showing without the validation for the stt_start text. However, I didn't add the code for the autocomplete within the validation because it didn't work with me. https://jsfiddle.net/cuoa3Lfe/33/